# While connecting to amazon web services s3 storage its throwing an error 'type error expected string or byte like object'

Tags: python, django

I am new Django website development and now I am trying to connect my django website to amazon web services but the error which is I am facing is that I am not able to solve it. I thought anybody here could help .

```
settings.py


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') #This key I have set in another file 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') #This is also the same stored in another file
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage' #It's backend
```

And the profile is also not opening its showing an value error. Can please help me out?

Here is the error:

> if VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) is None:
>       **TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**
>       [02/Aug/2019 15:19:06] "POST /adform/ HTTP/1.1" 500 199049

I expected the output that the photo I upload should link with s3 storage but while linking its throwing an error .

Comment: You only included the settings file which doesn't help much with the resolution of your problem. Please include code (with sufficient context) where you actually connect to S3 and try to upload the file. Full stack trace of the error can also usually help.

Comment: @Misza Thanks for concern but what more you need in code please specify i will post it